# can we use clustering without target variables?

Tags: python, unsupervised-learning

This is Sample data ..

```
Inn  R   B   W  Eco     AVG     SR
111 368 432 30  5.11    12.27   14.4
94  359 444 24  4.85    14.96   18.5
47  187 202 13  5.55    14.38   15.54
59  273 279 16  5.87    17.06   17.44
34  132 140 9   5.66    14.67   15.56
135 437 536 33  4.89    13.24   16.24
1   0   1   1   0       0           1
```

Now I would like to Make a new column which is `Choice` with values as `Good`, `Bad`, `Moderate` Bowling option for each row. How can i achieve it?

Comment: Clustering is unsupervised learning, and happens without target variables only. But the goal of clustering is to group `similar` data points together. You'd have to "define" what `Good`, `Bad`, and `Moderate` mean in your scenario. I'd rather just assign them based on Strike Rate, Economy, or Average, or a combination of those.

Comment: That brings another scenario in picture . can we find feature importance as we don't have target variable as of now ?

Comment: No. There's no straight-forward way to do that.